# How does one print an iso timestamp in a smart contract

Tags: time

I'm trying to print an ISO timestamp with second accuracy.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>    
time_t current_time = current_time_point().sec_since_epoch() * 1000;
char* charTime = std::put_time( std::localtime(&current_time), "%FT%T%z" );
print(charTime);
```

I've tried several combinations. I keep getting complaints about the namespace:

```
error: no member named 'localtime' in namespace 'std'
```

What is the correct way of doing this using cdt 1.6.1?

Answer (score 2):

eosio.cdt doesn't support time library in its libc, so you cannot use time related functions. `eoscc`, a customized version of eosio.cdt, supports it. (I'm a writer of that)

You can check it from [here](https://github.com/turnpike2/eoscc).

- Use `std::strftime` instead of `std::put_time`. put_time needs stream.
- `std::time_t` accepts seconds, so do not multiply `time_point::sec_since_epoch()` with 1000.
- Use `std::gmtime` instead of `std::localtime`. localtime requires timezone.
- In contract runtime, timezone info is not available, so you had better use the format "%FT%T" (or "%FT%TZ" for indicating UTC).

```
char buffer[32];
time_t current_time = current_time_point().sec_since_epoch();
std::strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%FT%TZ", std::gmtime(&current_time));
print(buffer);
```