# How can i convert a time_point to a string?

Tags: eosio-code, eosiocpp, time, string, eos-studio

I want to convert a time_point variable to a string using eos studio. I need to insert a time_point variable in a string in order to creare the object of my smart contract.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one print an iso timestamp in a smart contract](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/5218/how-does-one-print-an-iso-timestamp-in-a-smart-contract)

Answer (score 0):

below is my code:

```
struct TimePoint_micro_sec {
    int64_t count;

    [[nodiscard]] std::string  ToString() const;
};

std::string TimePoint_micro_sec::ToString() const {
    const uint64_t    seconds      = count / 1'000'000ULL;
    const uint64_t    milliseconds = (count % 1'000'000ULL) / 1'000ULL;
    const std::string padded_ms    = std::to_string(milliseconds + 1'000ULL).substr(1);
    const auto        ptime        = boost::posix_time::from_time_t(time_t(seconds));
    return boost::posix_time::to_iso_extended_string(ptime) + "." + padded_ms;
}
```